# Cannot listen/use any port on my windows

Tags: windows-7, port

I have windows 7, 
and my PC cannot use any port, i tried apache2, and it says it cannot bind to port 80, i changed to many different port, 8080, 81, 82 ....
i tried mysql, same thing happened, it cannot listen to any port
even tomcat didnt work.
i lunched cport (which was shipped with easyphp) and it gave me blank list, usually it gives me list or the process and the ports they are using,
i even tried "netstat -nao" it didnt show to me any process.

all these programmes are lunched in regular and administrators modes.

What's wrong here? is it a service down or something?

EDIT:
I cannot even ping to 127.0.0.1
i get "ping general failure"

Comment: Did you check the Firewall?

Comment: i disabled the firewall, and i noticed that i cant even ping to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Please check your other security software as well. Antivirus software. Try rebooting the machine once and try again